# Laravel Checking whether it has data or not from the model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am receiving the data from url and sending it to the model to and then displaying in the model like this.

```
public function BlogDisplay($data=NULL)
    {
        $BlogData = BlogModel::where('BlogLink', '=', $data)->get();
        return View::make('Blogs', array('BlogData' => $BlogData));
```

And then in the view.

But to check whether it has the data or not I am doing that in the view like this:

```
<?php

   if($BlogData)
   {
     var_dump($BlogData);
     echo 'has data';
   }
   else
   {
     var_dump($BlogData);
     echo 'has no data';
   }
?>
```

But both of the it shows the array.

How can i check whether it given $data exist or not in the database.

Comment: `if (!$BlogData->isEmpty()) { ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely getting back an `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection` object and the **truthy** check is coming back as true since the object is there. What you can do though is use the `isEmpty()` method built into that object.

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty

In your view:

```
@if ($BlogData->isEmpty())
    Nothing Here
@else 
    Got data!
@endif
```

Comment: That was great !! Got it !! Will accept answer in 3 min :)