# Dealing with data not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, error-handling

Laravel has a built-in method called `findOrfail()` described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models):

> Not Found Exceptions
>
> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query. However, if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown:
>
> $model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);
>
> $model = App\Flight::where('legs', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();

But what if you want to write your own code which deals with no result found. So in my controller I want something like:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data = JobCardHead::where('JobCardNum', $id)->first();

    If no data found then 
       some code
    else
       some code
```

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660175/laravel-checking-whether-it-has-data-or-not-from-the-model. i.e. it returns always a model that you can check to be empty or not. Or start to fill in and use as a model. It does make sense. I like it although I have a 'isFromDB()' method on the model. (I don't use Laravel - similar idea though). i.e. if returning an object always return one but it may be empty.

Answer (score 1):

What does Eloquent return in case no model is found for the methods that do not throw an exception? I'm guessing it's either `null` or `false`. So, you could check the return value of the `first()` call:

```
$data = JobCardHead::where('JobCardNum', $id)->first();

if ($data) {
  // found it
} else {
  // not found
}
```

Or, knowing that `firstOrFail()` throws an exception, you could wrap the call in a try/catch block:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

//..

try {
    $data = JobCardHead::where('JobCardNum', $id)->first();
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    // Data not found. Here, you should make sure that the absence of $data won't break anything
}

// Here $data is an instance of the model you wanted
```

The exact approach you should pick actually depends on your usecase a lot.

**UPD.** By the way, if `$id` here is your primary key here, you should simply use `find($id)` or `findOrFail($id)`, [as described here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel returns `null` on `first()` calls to your model when no records are returned.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1548

So for example you could do this as an even cleaner solution:

```
public function show($id)
{
    if ($job = JobCardHead::where('JobCardNum', $id)->first()) {
        // Record was found!

        return view('job.show', compact('job'));
    }

    return view('404');
}
```